# How to increment values in firebase realtime database python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have the exact same question as this one but in python :

[How to increment values in Firebase Realtime Database (v9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045141/how-to-increment-values-in-firebase-realtime-database-v9)

Is it actually implemented or not ? Because i am unable to find how to perform a :

```
from firebase_admin import db

realtime_db = db.reference(path="/", app=app, url="myurl")
realtime_db.update({
   f"chats/{uid}/num": db.increment(1),
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't seem to exist in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db).  Maybe you could file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python).

Comment: Thanks for confirming because i did look at the documentation and could not find it, i will raise an issue / feature request :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [documentation of the Python Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db) there doesn't seem to be an implementation of the `increment` operation there.

Luckily, that operation just gives you a sentinel value to send to the server, and you can create that yourself too based on the [example in the documentation for the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values). It should be something like this:

```
realtime_db.update({
   f"chats/{uid}/num": { ".sv": { "increment": 1 }},
})
```

Syntax errors in the above example are definitely possible, so let me know about any of those you encounter and fix below please.

Comment: Thanks Frank will take a look at it and accept your answer once it works (hopefully !)